# ASP.NET Core Web API : filter the Get method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I need to use a get method to get the packages with given facilities and I need to pass multiple packages as parameter.

I have written a method but it always returns null.

My method:

```
public IEnumerable<GetPackageDto> GetPackagesByFacilities(IEnumerable<Facilities> facilities)
{
    var packages = _context.Packages
                           .Where(p => p.Facilities.Contains(facilities.ToString())).ToList();

    if (packages == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    var packagesDto = _mapper.Map<List<GetPackageDto>>(packages);

    return packagesDto;
}
```

Http endpoint:

```
[HttpGet("facilities")]
public ActionResult GetPackageByFacilities([FromQuery]IEnumerable<Facilities> facilities) 
{
    var packages = _packageManagement.GetPackagesByFacilities(facilities);

    if (packages == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return Ok(packages);
}
```

I had tried the given code it returns an empty list.

I need to get packages that has the facilities and I need to select multiple values as facilities.

Comment: Can you please share your entity classes?

Comment: What exactly do you think `facilities.ToString()` does? You'll definitley be in for a surprise when you find out.

Comment: Also move `facilities.ToString()` to a variable and check it's value.

Comment: Could you post your Package.cs & Facilities.cs code?

Answer (score 1):

In this expression :`var packages = _context.Packages.Where(p => p.Facilities.Contains(facilities.ToString())).ToList();`  , `facilities.ToString()` is not true.

If you want to select packages that have **at least** one of **facilities**, use the following query:

```
var packages = _context.Packages.Where(p =>p.Facilities.Any(c=>facilities.Contains(c).ToList();
```

If you want to select packages that have **all of** the **facilities** use the following query instead:

```
var packages = _context.Packages.Where(p =>p.Facilities.All(c=>facilities.Contains(c).ToList();
```

Comment: I highly doubt that EF will be able to translate this.

Comment: You are right @GuruStron; those are supposed to be changed to  `var packages = _context.Packages.Where(p =>p.Facilities.Any(c=>facilities.Contains(c).ToList();` and 
`var packages = _context.Packages.Where(p =>p.Facilities.All(c=>facilities.Contains(c).ToList();`, I've changed them. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

In your HttpGet method, it says you are passing the Facilities from a Query.
This is a highly unusual way of doing things. Is it a requirement?

Depending on your Facilities.cs implementation, that query would look very strange. Using Facilities.ToString() almost certainly behaves in a way that you do not want it to behave.

Maybe a good alternative would be to pass in a list of IDs of Facilities through the query parameters and then using the IDs in your search.

Then, presuming we have the IDs of all the facilities we need the packages from, we can write a query:

```
_context.Facilities.Where(f => listOfIds.Contains(f.Id)).Include(f => f.Packages).ToList();
```

Facility to Package is a one to many relationship (One Facility can hold many packages, but a package can belong to only 1 facility.)

So if you'd like to get all the packages for a number of given facilities, the query above is what I would use.

Then you could use a little bit of LINQ to further select only the packages that you need, or perhaps refactor your mapper.